# File not found when reading in truffle abi file

Tags: javascript, json, web3js, truffle

I am using truffle and web3 to assemble a smart contract that I deployed on Ropsten testnet. I did the following:

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const fs = require('fs')
const { token_abi } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./build/contracts/QUAD_EK.json', 'utf8'))
```

I get the following error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './build/contracts/QUAD_EK.json'`

My file structure below [image: enter image descripfe]

Comment: Check you are running your script from the root folder of your project.

Comment: I think I am doing that? I'm running:

`truffle exec ./scripts/batch-transfer-tokens.js --network ropsten`